# Auto update arguments of implementing class in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, inheritance, shortcut

Let's say I use the factory design and have the interface :

```
public interface IEvent {
void doSomething (String a);
}
```

And the implementing classes

```
public class EventA implements IEvent{
@Override
void doSomething(String a) { ... }
}

public class EventB implements IEvent{
@Override
void  doSomething(String a) { ... }
}
```

But now I decided that I wanted to change the method in the interface to be :

```
void doSomething(String a, int b)
```

Is there a quick way in Eclipse to update all the classes that implement this method to have the new arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the method selected, you can press Alt+Shift+C to bring up the "Change method signature" dialog. There you can add/remove parameters and it will be updated in all calling and implementig classes.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the method and Refactor > Change Method Signature...